# Geopandas to_file() gives an error regarding fiona.drivers(). Is it possible to work around this?

Tags: geopandas, fiona

I'm using geopandas to get WKT and coordinates from a database:

```
df = pandas.read_sql(con=conn2, sql=test_query)

df['Coordinates'] = df['WKT'].apply(lambda x: wkt.loads(x.read()))

gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='Coordinates')

loc = r"...\Layers\geopandastest2.shp"
gdf.to_file(loc)
```

When I use to_file() it gives me the following error:

> C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py:108: FionaDeprecationWarning: Use fiona.Env() instead.
>     with fiona.drivers():

Is it possible to get around this and force to_file() to use fiona.Env() or do I need to wait for geopandas to be updated?

Relevant geopandas github issue: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/845

Comment: What version of geopandas and fiona are you using?  To get them you can use `geopandas.__version__` and `fiona.__version__`

Comment: And how did you install them?

Answer (score 0):

It is just a warning, your file should be saved anyway. It is already fixed in Geopandas Master (https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/854), which should be released soon.

You don't have to do anything about it now, it does not affect your script.